# Is this reasoning for interchanging limit and integral for $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-1}^4 \frac{t^2 x\sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}dx$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I must use the following theorem

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $f(x,t)$ be a function defined on $E \times A$. Assume that $f$ is integrable in $x$ for any $t \in A$ and continuous in $t\in A$ for almost all $x \in E$, and that there exists an integrable function $g$ such that $|f(x,t)| \le g(x)$ for almost all $x \in E$ and for any $t \in A$. Then the function
> $$F(t)=\int_E f(x,t) dx$$
> Is continuous in $A$.

To show that I can interchange the limit with the integral in the following
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-1}^4 \frac{t^2 x\sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}dx$$
And evaluate it.
My work: let $t_0>0$ and let $f:[-1,4] \times (t_0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by letting $f(x,t)=\frac{t^2 x \sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}$.

Since any interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable with the Lebesgue measure, $[-1,4]$ is a measurable set of $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $(t_0,\infty)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

For $t \in (t_0, \infty)$ the function $x \mapsto \frac{t^2 x \sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}$ is continuous for any $x \in [-1,4]$ since it is a ratio of continuous functions of $x$ and $1+t^2 x^2 \ne 0$ for any $x \in [-1,4]$ and for any $t \in (t_0, \infty)$; hence, since $[-1,4]$ is compact, it is integrable for any $x\in[-1,4]$. Since $t \in (t_0,\infty)$ is arbitrary, this holds for any $t \in (t_0, \infty)$ and so $f$ is integrable for any $x \in [-1,4]$ and for any $t \in (t_0,\infty)$.

For $x \in [-1,4]$ the function $t\mapsto \frac{t^2 x \sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}$ is continuous for any $t \in (t_0,\infty)$ since it is a ratio of continuous function of $t$ in $(t_0,\infty)$ $1+t^2x^2 \ne 0$ for any $t \in (t_0,\infty)$ and for any $x\in[-1,4]$; since $x \in [-1,4]$ is arbitrary, this holds for any $x \in [-1,4]$ and so, in particular, it holds for almost all $x \in [-1,4]$. So $f$ is continuous for any $t \in (t_0,\infty)$ and for almost all $x\in[-1,4]$.

Since for any $t \in (t_0,\infty)$ and for any $x\in [-1,4]$ it is $0<1+t^2 x^2 <t^2 x^2$, it follows that
$$\left|\frac{t^2 x \sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}\right|=\frac{t^2 |x|\sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2} < \frac{t^2|x|\sqrt{|x|}}{t^2 x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{|x|}, \forall x\in[-1,4], \forall t\in(t_0,\infty)$$
And the function $g:[-1,4] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x):=\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{|x|}$ is integrable in $[-1,4]$, because its integral converges:
$$\int_{-1}^4 \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{|x|} dx=6$$
Hence, the hypotheses of the theorem are satisfied; so
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{-1}^4 \frac{t^2 x\sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^4 \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^2 x\sqrt{|x|}}{1+t^2 x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^4 \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{x}dx$$
$$=[2\sqrt{-x}]_{-1}^0+[2\sqrt{x}]_0^4=2$$
Since I have nearly zero experience with these kind of exercises, is everything I said correct or is there something wrong (and I ask you to correct me, please) or that I could have said in a better way? Specifically, I have introduced $t_0$ because I believe that the open set $A$ of the theorem, in this case, should be a neighborhood of $\infty$ since I am interested in the limit as $t \to \infty$, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: The integration limits for the negative $x$ are from $-1$ to $0$, not to $4$ (last line in the last formula)

Comment: @温泽海: Thanks for the help!
Andrei: Thank you for noticing the typo!

Comment: One minor point. The original integrand is an odd function so $\int_{-1}^1=0$. Thus you could have just used $\int_1^4$ and gotten rid of the absolute value.